# HttpClient: Can't get data from external URL

Tags: angular, http

I have a very basic (GET-) request fetching some kind of data (case-list.service.ts):

```
fetchCase(caseId: string) {
  return this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:54355/api/case/' + caseId);
}
```

I need that kind of URL because my backend is on another port.
However, I'm getting an error, and the request is not being executed:

> ERROR Error: resource is required
>           at viewWrappedDebugError (core.es5.js:8422)
>           at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13477)
>           at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (core.es5.js:13007)
>           at ViewRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ViewRef_.detectChanges
>   (core.es5.js:10174)
>           at core.es5.js:4812
>           at Array.forEach ()
>           at ApplicationRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ApplicationRef_.tick (core.es5.js:4812)
>           at core.es5.js:4684
>           at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (zone.js:392)
>           at Object.onInvoke (core.es5.js:3890)

But, when I replace that URL with a local one (e.g. `'/api/case/' + caseId`), it works as expected.

The localhost-URL is not the problem. I tried it with entering http://www.google.de/something, and it threw the same error as with the localhost address.

Any ideas why this is not working?
Any help is appreciated :)

@Update: 
I subscribe to that observable in my component controller:
case-list.component.ts:

```
    this.caseListService.fetchCase(this.caseId).subscribe( (res) => {

      console.log(res);
      // comment in when backend is available
      // this.case = res;
    });
```

Comment: What happens when you go to this url directly `'http://localhost:54355/api/case/' + caseId` ??

Comment: It's not available because my backend doesn't work yet. Nevertheless, it should give me a 404 and not crash completely. It worked perfectly with Http (which is deprecated unfortunately now)

Comment: `this.caseListService.fetchCase(this.caseId).subscribe(
    res => {
        console.log(res);
        // comment in when backend is available
        // this.case = res;
    },
    error => {
        console.log(error);
    }
);
`
if you try this does the console.log in error block gets printed??

Comment: Nope - also if I add the error function, nothing changes. It doesn't even get to this part since it's failing in this.http.get() line already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in my case I was a wrongly configured HTTP_INTERCEPTOR. The external URL was not added there.

Thanks all for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private http: HttpClient;
fetchCase(caseId: string) {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:54355/api/case/' + caseId).subscribe(data => {
        // Read the result field from the JSON response.get response
        caseId = data['rows'];
    });
    return caseId;
}
```

Try this. I think subscribe is necessary to make a get request. Since there is nothing to hold on to for the return.

Comment: I'm doing that. I'm returning the entire Observable, and in the other class I subscribe to it. I updated my answer to make it more clear :)